# Different elements in Group in Expandable ListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

i have a problem, i want to add different elements to one Group in expandable listView, like in a picture. It is possible?[image] I know, that i must to cgange my getChildView method in adapter?

```
 case 2:
                    if (childPosition==0){
                        infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
                        txtListChild=(TextView)convertView
                                .findViewById(R.id.tv_group_name) ;
                        txtListChild.setText("Вот они, родненькие условия использования)");
                    }
                    else{
                    c = db.getAccamulativeListOfCompany(companyID);
                    infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_accumulative_list, null);
                    txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
                    Log.d("myLogs", "group_pos=" + groupPosition + "," + childPosition);
                    TextView tvDiscount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_accumulative_discount);
                    ImageView ivAccamulative = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_accamulative_item);

                    if (c != null) {
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                            c.moveToPosition(childPosition-1);


                            txtListChild.setText(c.getString(1) + " руб.");

                            tvDiscount.setText(c.getString(2) + "%");
                            File imgFile = new File(c.getString(4));
                            if (imgFile.exists()) {
                                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                ivAccamulative.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    }
                    break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, I assume those are child views you want different types of.

In that case, override the functions below, returning the number of different child layouts you expect to produce in getChildTypeCount, and the logic for assigning a unique integer (1 to count), corresponding to each layout, using group and child position as parameters, in getChildType.

In the getChildView method, then you will inflate your different layouts, according to the logic of your getChildType method.  Calling it here is probably a good idea, and using switch on the return value to determine which layout to inflate.

You don't have to overwrite the layout of views each time they are recycled if you do this, the ExpandedListView will take care of ensuring that when the views are recycled, you will only get the type of view that matches the logic in your getChildType method.

The uncomplicated alternative is to simply inflate whatever view you need in the getView / getChildView methods, but of course that's not terribly efficient.

```
public class MyAwesomeAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


@Override
public int getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

            // Return a number here, 1 to whatever you return in getChildTypeCount.
            // Each number should correspond to a particular layout, using group
            // and child position to determine which layout to produce. 

    return super.getChildType(groupPosition, childPosition);
}

@Override
public int getChildTypeCount() {

            // Return the number of distinct layouts you expect to create

    return super.getChildTypeCount();
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int gp, int cp, boolean arg2, View view, ViewGroup arg4) {

    if(view == null){

      switch(getChildType(gp, cp)){

       case 1: 
           //inflate type 1
           break;


       case 2:
          //inflate type 2
           break;

       ....


       }
}
```

}
}

Comment: i try it, but i have problem, i have 1 item (text) and 4 items in cursor, in result i have: first item -text, and 3 next is from cursor. I loose 1 item from cursor.

Comment: adjust your get child count to give you an extra child? Since you're adding one item not in the cursor.  It appears you are already shifting the index for your cursor accordingly.

Comment: Bur i decrement index of cursor c.moveToPosition(childPosition-1); How can i add one more child?

Comment: have getChildCount return m_cursor.getCount + 1; assuming the cursor represents all the children you want to display.  If you are dynamically figuring out how many children you have, by fetching cursors, you don't want to fetch the cursor in GetChildView, because by then GetChildCount has already been called.

Comment: i know it, but how i don't have getChildCount() method, and i don't know where it called. Can you show me in code, how to solve this.

Comment: public int getChildrenCount(int arg0); are you using "baseexpandablelistadapter" or simply a base adapter?  If you're using the "expandable" one, then it should be there by default, if not, open source, override methods, and click it in eclipse.

Comment: thank you a lot. I does not see this method, i try to do this in getChildTypeCount().

Comment: @NameSpace in my case if I try to access getChildType(..) , it always returning me 0...why so. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: That's the default return value, you have to put your own logic that gives a return type for a given position.  Android will then use the logic to organize separate pools of recycled views for each return type.  This way you don't have to rebuild each view type from scratch, and can greatly improve performance.